# WSO2 GREG : MySQL SQLException Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x91200...'

Tags: mysql, jdbc, wso2-governance-registry

I get the following error after running `wso2server.bat -Dsetup`

using `mysql_connector_java_5.1.38_bin_1.0.0.jar. Registry 5.1 Win 7`

It doesn't seem to matter if I previously run the `dbscripts\mysql.sql` or not.
The database was definitely created with `create database regdb character set latin1`

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x91200...' for column 'UM_DESCRIPTION' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.addClaimMapping(ClaimDAO.java:228)
```

Comment: looks like the source of the problem is the 'character set latin1' .Omit this requirement & the error goes away. But maybe I'm just swapping this for a new one further down the path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue i solved this by converting the column **UM_DESCRIPTION** from the table **um_claim** from latin-1 to utf-8.

See more here : [Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x91200.. when starting up with Latin1 in Windows](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-15087)